How to make VSCode recognize assembly? "code language not supported or defined."
I am trying to write assembly with NASM installed on Windows 11, 64bit OS. However, VSCode wont recognize it or use NASM, neither in the terminal or using the Run extension.
I have tried editing the c_cpp_properties.json and modifying system environment variables in Path to include NASM.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
